# Google Maps Android API Authorization failure, despite SHA1 keys registered

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, sha1

- Developing an Android app locally using Android Studio 1.3
- Small closed beta on Google Play Store One API key registered against this one app with two SHA1 keys - one local, and one for the release-signed APK using our organisation's Android keystore
- Google Maps works locally while connected to the PC via Android Studio
- Google Maps fails when downloaded via the Play store produces a blank grey map with Google logo with this error in logs

  ```
  5967-6038/? E/Google Maps Android API﹕In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
  Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
  Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
  API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE
  Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 
  23:C9:76:CA:A6:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:91:9B:80:3F;org.bto.btapp
  ```
- SHA1 keys registered against developer console:
  [image: developer-console screenshot]
- Output from keytool (debug local)
  [image: local-keystore-output]
- Output from keytool (release keystore used to sign APK on Play store beta)
  [image: release-keystore-output]
- Have checked the obvious (am I using the correct API key)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether you have copy pasted your API key in google_maps_api.xml in values folder. From the error log(i'm assuming), your API key is shown as "YOUR_KEY_HERE", that's exactly the default value in the file. Please check.

**UPDATE**
[image: IMG]

Open the google_maps_api.xml and paste your api key at "YOUR_KEY_HERE". That will do it.

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

references:

<string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">AIza[some_other_letters]kQ</string>

Comment: This is from your manifest.xml right..? You have to provide the API key in the google_maps_api.xml also. Check the above image

Comment: Yes, the string resource referenced is within google_maps_api.xml as set out by the Google Android API instructions.

Just done a search for YOUR_KEY_HERE and it's located a different google_maps_api.xml that is not referenced anywhere on the Android Studio project tree. Suspect that'll fix it - will report back after uploaded/tried

Comment: Then check if you have any extra spaces at the end of the key. I had that error once.

Comment: OK. That is the case - there are two versions of the file google_maps_api.xml, one for debug one for release, but the release one is invisible on the project tree. Not sure whether this is an artefact of the way my project was created, or whether this is something inherent to the version of Android Studio I was using, but all fixed now. Thanks